# Wireless headphones sound garbled on Samsung Galaxy A54

Tags: bluetooth

My Cowin E7 bluetooth headphones suddenly have garbled sound when connecting to Samsung Galaxy A54.  They work fine with other devices (including other Samsung/Android devices) and I have also used my husband's headphones, which are also Cowin E7 brand and his work fine on my phone.

I am truly stumped by this issue.  I've tried rebooting my phone.  Turning Bluetooth off and back on and still get the same garbled sound.  It just doesn't make sense.  I recently updated my phone, but that surely couldn't be the issue since my husband's identical headphones work fine with my phone.

I have also unpaired and repaired the headphones and that has failed to fix the problem.

If anyone has any suggestions I haven't yet tried, please let me know.  It will be much appreciated.